# Is it possible to apply a texture of an image to a mesh/sculpt for 3d printing?

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I'm new to blender(about 1 day in), and I don't exactly know how to word my question properly. I am using blender to sculpt stuff to resin print. I'm currently trying to make something with a burlap texture(see image below). Would it be possible to apply the texture of the image to the mesh so it can be 3d printed? Or do I just have to try and sculpt the entire texture. If you know any sort of solution/shortcut please teach me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blende.SE. You'll need a lot of geometry for that! If you machine can handle it, the way is to use the "displace modifier" after a proper unwrap of the model using the image as a depthmap. Do some research about this and come back if you have troubles.

Comment: for testing you can use Materialize (https://boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/) to create a heightmap (Diffuse -> Height) from the image.